# What is data store for the Reference Tokens in .net, and where they are stored?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Who can explain what means data store and where it is located in the sentence below?`

> IdentityServer will store the contents of the token in a data store, where is the physical location?

The sentence is taken from here: [Reference Tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docs](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html):

> IdentityServer is designed for extensibility, and one of the extensibility points is the storage mechanism used for data that IdentityServer needs. This quickstart shows how to configure IdentityServer to use EntityFramework (EF) as the storage mechanism for this data (rather than using the in-memory implementations we had been using up until now).
>
> [...]
>
> These stores are modeled with interfaces, and we provide an EF implementation of these interfaces in the IdentityServer4.EntityFramework Nuget package.

It can store anywhere, it's up to you to configure it. Entity Framework is one example of a storage provider, installed through the package `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework`.

Comment: There is question where are IdentityServer4 store reference tokens, is there any short and correct answer for this?

Comment: @Sargis The answer explains that they are stored wherever you set them up to be stored - in a text file, in a database, in a cache, in memory, .... it's completely up to you.

Comment: @Sargis what part of my answer don't you understand? You must configure a store. Entity Framework is one of the options, which will then store it in a relational database such as SQL Server, depending on your connection string and configured providers.

Comment: @CodeCaster
 For example I use .net core EF, identityServer4 and have connection for local DB, I mean can I find physically it in the DB or somewhere else?